# Sort doesn't use natural order

Tags: sort, uniq

I have used `uniq -c` and `sort` extensively on other machines, and it always worked very well.

Now, on my new Ubuntu (13.04) machine, I end up with a weird ordering:

```
% cat queries.log | grep INSERT | sort | uniq -c | sort
      1 INSERT INTO A (id, organization_id) VALUES (?, ?)
      2 INSERT INTO B (id, resource_id) VALUES (?, ?)
      2 INSERT INTO C (id) VALUES (?)
      2 INSERT INTO D (email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
      3 INSERT INTO E (user_id, type) VALUES (?, ?)
  40275 INSERT INTO F (id, resource_id) VALUES (?, ?)
  40283 INSERT INTO G (action_id, role_id, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
      6 INSERT INTO H (id, resource_id) VALUES (?, ?)
```

Why is `6` after `40283`?

And how can I end up with the expected "natural" order?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to supply the `-n` option to enable numerical sort,

```
   -n, --numeric-sort
          compare according to string numerical value
```

Comment: Yipee! I don't remember using that flag before, is it possible it is enabled by default on some systems?

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli I don't think so, or at least I haven't seen it that way. Perhaps you had it set as an alias? By the way, you might also want to check out `sort -g` which can deal with more complex numbers like `5e-12`.